# Rest Framework Django - Disable field to accept null values

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Rest Framework Django - Disable field to accept null values

How can I configure for the serialized Model to accept blank fields?

Warning

```
{"Operacao": ["This field can not be blank."]}
```

Model

```
class SEF(models.Model):
    operacao = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    documento = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Serializer

```
class SEFCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = SEF
        fields = ('operacao', 'documento', 'user')
```

View

```
sef_create = SEFCreateSerializer(data=data, many=True)
        if sef_create.is_valid():
            sef_create.save()
            salvo = HTTP_200_OK
        else:
            salvo = sef_create.errors
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Include allow_blank=True in the field definition as this:

```
operacao = serializers.CharField(allow_blank=True, allow_null=True)
```

Answer (score 8):

```
class SEFCreateSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = SEF
        fields = ('operacao', 'documento', 'user')
        extra_kwargs = {'operacao': {'required': False}}
```

Comment: Really easy way to do this with model fields that you don't need to change any other thing that `requiered=False`... Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 6):

You can set default value like

```
operacao = models.CharField(max_length=10, default=0)
```

if you specify a field in model like this it will take default value as 0 if nothing is present.

or in serializer

```
operacao = serializers.CharField(allow_null = True)
```

Comment: operacao = serializers.CharField(allow_null = True) . ----   Does not Work

Comment: operacao = models.CharField(max_length=10, default=0) .  ----  Does not work too.